# Is there a three.js API

Tags: three.js

is there sth like a real API of three.JS? I only found http://threejs.org/docs/ but this doesn't seem to cover the API as e.g. fontloader is not referenced.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: what do you mean IntelliSense, code completion ?

Comment: I mean sth like a documentation of the API. What objects, what methods, what parameters what return values, things to consider etc. Like e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html for the Hashtable in Java